# `openxlsx`: load and apply all formatting from the read file

Tags: r, openxlsx

I try to read in a spreadsheet that consists of one sheet and then add a new sheet to this file. So I read the data into R with `openxlsx::read.xlsx`, but in doing so I also lose the formatting of the first sheet.

Any ideas on how I can preserve the formatting of the first sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the `loadWorkbook` function which reads in the whole Excel file as is and then you can use `addWorksheet`, `writeData` and `saveWorkbook` to add a worksheet, fill it with data and save the whole thing - which should presever the formatting of your original sheets.